# Python Function: Tuple as argument and return sorted

Tags: python

I need help answering this question because I really can't understand it.
Write a function that takes a tuple as an argument and returns the tuple sorted?
Any help will be appreciated!

Here is what I've done so far..

```
def tuple:
     return tuple(sorted)
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Well, I'm not asking for the answer @Alessiox.
TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I don't understand "tuple as an argument"

Comment: But which bit of that didn't you understand? Do you know what tuples are? Do you know what arguments are?

Comment: @Sam.C, then the question is not a programming question and does not belong to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Alessiox, homework is [allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow as long as it "include[s] a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." (Granted, this question doesn't currently have either of those things, but that doesn't make "no homework on SO" true)

Comment: @Kevin, indeed I pointed out "Please show some effort in solving your problem". Maybe I should have said "no homeworks from scratch on SO", my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what they expect:

```
def sorttuple(a):
     ... do something, like sorting..
    return b


a=(3,2,1)
b=sorttuple(a)
print b
```

output:

```
  (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the `sorted()` method

```
def sort_tuple(unsorted):
      return tuple(sorted(unsorted))
```